Реакция бота на добавление его в чат
Как заставить бота написать 'Привет!' Когда его добавили в чат

Пример для aiogram:
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
   bot_obj = await bot.get_me()
   bot_id = bot_obj.id

   for chat_member in message.new_chat_members:
      if chat_member.id == bot_id:
          await message.reply("Привет!")

На будущее: ищите тип нужного события в документации к общему API телеграмма, а затем просто смотрите его обработку в документации к конкретной библиотеке.Возможно определённое событие не обрабатывается вовсе.
